# Server refusing to load a specific .css

Tags: windows-server-2003

I have installed a version of Sitecore Intranet Portal for one of our customers. We now have the problem that the stylesheet can't be loaded. After a while we get a 504 error. In Firefox everything is working fine as this will just load the old stylesheet that loaded before. The new stylesheet won't be loaded and just gives a gateway error.
Could this be server side caching or whatever? If so, how can we test / solve this problem.
The website is running on a Windows 2003 R2 server with 3gb ram.
When i'm renaming the stylesheet i am able to load the stylesheet, but when i rename it back to it's old name it refuses to load and gives back the 504 error.

The name of the css file is:

FileDropAreaIconsView.css

Comment: Have you got any proxies in between?

Comment: No there is no proxy in between.

Comment: Normally, I would start by looking at the HTML and validating the URL to the CSS file. Then trying to download the CSS file in a browser while watching the logs to see what, if any error comes up on downloading that file.

a 504 response indicates that the server itself is acting as a proxy. http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html This is all self contained within a single installation of IIS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try turning off usermode caching at the IIS end:

IIS7:
http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/caching

IIS6:
http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/0fc16fe7-be45-4033-a5aa-d7fda3c993ff.mspx

That way, if there is any "transparent" proxy in between, you will be able to control it.. somewhat.